# lx86cl: No such file or directory common clozure lisp

Tags: common-lisp, ccl, slackware, clozure-cl

I am on a slackware and I have successfully installed common clozure lisp but when running ccl in shell prompt I have the following error message:

```
>  /usr/local/bin/ccl64: line 81: /usr/local/bin//lx86cl64: No such file
> or directory
>     bash-4.3# ccl64 
>     /usr/local/bin/ccl64: line 81: /usr/ccl/scripts/lx86cl64: No such file or directory
>     bash-4.3# ./ccl64 
>     ./ccl64: line 81: /usr/ccl/scripts/lx86cl64: No such file or directory
>     bash-4.3#
```

I followed the instructions and copied the two files into

**/usr/local/bin**

from **/usr/ccl/scripts/** installation directory as follows:

**My local bin here below:**

```
bash-4.3# pwd
    /usr/local/bin
    bash-4.3# ls -l
    total 8
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1389 Mar 10 10:52 ccl
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1734 Mar 10 10:52 ccl64
    bash-4.3#
```

The scripts installation directory is as below:

```
bash-4.3# pwd
/usr/ccl/scripts
bash-4.3# ls -l c*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1399 Nov  6  2015 ccl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1744 Mar  6 22:28 ccl64
bash-4.3#
```

The lx86cl is located as below:

```
bash-4.3# pwd
/usr/ccl
bash-4.3# ls -l lx*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   182924 Mar  5 20:52 lx86cl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18231312 Nov  6  2015 lx86cl.image
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   201168 Mar  5 20:52 lx86cl64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24871152 Nov  6  2015 lx86cl64.image
bash-4.3#
```

The configuration modified lines for the two files in my /usr/local/bin/
is as follows:

```
   if [ -z "$CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY" ]; then
   CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY=/usr/ccl/scipts
   fi




CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY="C:/cygwin$CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY"
```

same happens if I put the /usr/ccl instead of /usr/ccl/scripts

```
  if [ -z "$CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY" ]; then
  CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY=/usr/ccl
  fi


   CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY="C:/cygwin$CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY"



bash-4.3# ccl
/usr/local/bin/ccl: line 48: /usr/ccl/scripts/lx86cl: No such file or directory
bash-4.3# 

bash-4.3# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/kde4/libexec:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin
```

Comment: Slackware or Cygwin?  Also, why are you running it as root?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `/usr/local/bin//lx86cl64` is not found. If I look at your `ls -l` from `/usr/local/bin`, that seems to be true.

So, why not just copy the required files there:

```
cp /usr/ccl/lx86cl* /usr/local/bin
```

As you said that you are on Slackware, that should work.

Not sure what you are doing with the cygwin. It seems not appropriate  for Slackware, and you may be editing is a part of the script that is only executed when run under cygwin.

Comment: `(cd /usr/local/bin && ln -s ../../ccl/lx86cl* .)` better to symlink.